# Why does ListDensityPlot give different profiles for the same data when x and y data excluded?

Tags: plotting, data

I have data of the form $\{x,y,z\}$, and `ListDensityPlot` gives different profiles if we exclude $x$ and $y$ points. Here is an example

```
dat1 = Table[{x, y, Sin[x  y]}, {x, -π, π, π/5}, {y, -π, π, π/2}];
dat2 = Table[Sin[x  y], {x, -π, π, π/5}, {y, -π, π, π/2}];
{ListDensityPlot[dat2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 200], 
 ListDensityPlot[Flatten[dat1, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 200]}
```

[image]

How can I get the correct profile from `dat2`, which must be the same as in `ListDensityPlot[Flatten[dat1, 1]]`?

Comment: The two data sets are structurally different. `Dimension[dat2]` returns `{11, 5}` whereas `Dimensions[Flatten[dat1, 1]]` returns `{55, 3}`. I don't see how they could return the same plot.

Comment: @MarcoB, I used `Flatten` to make it readable for `ListDensityPlot` but both data sets are the same where we removed only $x,$ and $y$ from the second one. I understand that in this case  `ListDensityPlot` must give the same profile since it will depend in both data on the $z$ component only

Comment: You need to plot `dat1[[All, All, 3]]` to get the same effect, and not `Flatten[dat1, 1]`.

Comment: `Flatten[dat1, 1]` and `dat1[[All, All, 3]]` gives the correct profile, how can I get the same profile from `dat2`?

Answer (score 1):

They are same just plot of `dat2` is transposed and also is missing data on top and right border of the plot and also plotting ranges are a bit shifted.

Why the border data is missing on `dat2` plot is not clear to me but it is quite possible that it is a bug. (see @Domen's comments bellow why he thinks it is not a bug)

I transposed the `dat2` and also changed plotting range appropriately to see that they are same. (except for missing border data)

```
dat1 = Table[{x, y, Sin[x  y]}, {x, -π, π, π/5}, {y, -π, π, π/2}];
dat2 = Table[Sin[x  y], {x, -π, π, π/5}, {y, -π, π, π/2}];

ListDensityPlot[Flatten[dat1, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> {{-π - π/10, π + π/10}, {-π - π/4, π + π/4}}]

ListDensityPlot[Transpose@dat2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 12}, {1, 6}}]
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a bug; see the last example under `Options > InteprolationOrder` in the documentation for [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html#1336125907): _For **irregular** data, zero-order interpolation gives Voronoi regions for each point_.

Comment: @Domen: I do not understand your point. Both plots use the same data and same `InterpolationOrder`.

Comment: No, they do not use the same type of data. `dat2` has _regular_ data, while `dat1` has _irregular_ data. See the distinction in the top of the documentation (`Details and Options`).

Comment: @Domen: They use the same data only first is scaled to the second. If first is irregular then the second must be too. The scaling of the data should be reflected only in different scale of axis but plots should be the same.

Comment: No, the distinction is made by whether you provide data as a rectangular array of values (regular data), or you also provide the explicit coordinates of the points (irregular data). It doesn't matter that these coordinates still fall on a rectangular grid; by providing them, this is treated as irregular data.

Comment: @Domen: Ahhh... I see now. They call it `irregular data` or `regular data` but this is misleading. It is one form of data or other form of data, I do not see nothing irregular or regular about it.

Comment: Regular means the values implicitly lie on a "regular" (ie. rectangular) grid. Irregular means you give arbitrary coordinates.